# Live sessions not showing in control panel

Tags: session, liferay

I am using liferay 6.1.1. I have enabled following properties in portal-ext.properties

```
live.users.enabled = true
session.tracker.friendly.paths.enabled=ture
session.tracker.persistence.enabled=true
```

But still I am not able to see live sessions in control panel. It shows message " There are no live sessions. ".

Answer (score 0):

Is the value `true` of `session.tracker.friendly.paths.enabled=ture` misspelt in the question only or it is the same value that you have given in the propertied file?

Comment: It is the same value in properties file. I just changed it.It was spelling mistake. I will check result after restarting tomcat.

Comment: Have checked it. But it is still not showing live sessions in control panel.